VB.NET - The Program Doesn't Read All The Images In The Folder
My Program In VB.NET Langauage.
This Is The Code :
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim g As Integer = 0
    Dim array_1(1000) As String

 Private Sub btn_Images_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Images.Click
        Dim Folder_1 = Directory.GetFiles("D:\Downloads\new folder411")
        For Each theFile As String In Folder_1
            array_1(g) = theFile
            g = g + 1
        Next
 End Sub

 Private Sub btn_ChangeImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_ChangeImage.Click
        i = i + 1
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(array_1(i))
        txt_Photo_URL.Text = array_1(i)
 End Sub

End Class

This program reads the images that in the folder. There are 106 images in the folder.
It reads when I click on the Images button. By click on this button , The program put the path of the images in an array.
By the click on the Change Image button , The program changes the image in the Picturebox.
The program start from the second image.
The names of the first nine images are : 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9.
And the names of other images are long names. For Example : 376556043_2169237486757695_4732290824127040386_n_2254033511621973
412463591_883118659859520_5848695112838062375_n_883118656526187
The Problem Is :
The program put the second image and the third image in the Picturebox.
But , These images : 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , The program doesn't put them in the Picturebox.
When I click on Change Image button to change from the third image to another image , The program make skip for 6 images and change the image to the image that has long name.
The program make this problem just with these 6 image.
It doesn't make this problem with the second and the third images , And the other images which has long names.
Why This Happen ? , And What Is The Solution ?

The following may be of interest: Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio

The first long name begins with 3, the name of the third file with a short name is 3, so...

For debugging purposes, you may consider copying 10 - 20 images to a new folder and debug your code using those images. Searching for vb.net string sorting numbers as string may also be helpful.

Your array's first entry is array_l(0), so put the i = i + 1 line at the bottom of the click event sub. You probably need to make sure that only image files are in your array. The files that aren't working are probably not image files.

If you want the images to appear in the same order as they do in Windows Explorer: Sorting an array of folder names like Windows Explorer (Numerically and Alphabetically) - VB.NET.

What guarantee is there that the files will be read in alphabetical order? There isn't. Sometimes in Windows on a long cut-and-paste of many files, you'll notice in Explorer that Windows, for some unknown reason, will sometimes move the first file, then the last file, then the "new" first file, then the "new" last file, etc., working towards "the center" of the file list in Windows Explorer. Debug your code, and observe the first 5 - 10 reads of the file paths. See if they are in fact being read in alpha order or not (i.e., debug and check the contents of your array).

@HardCode I made a debugging to the code. All Images are stored in Folder_1 array. But not in alphabetical order. The Images that were not appear like 4 , 5 and the other images I mentioned In the question ,  Were in the array. But in diffrent index. For Example : The image 4 was in index 37.  Now , I don't have problem if the program reads the images in not the alphabetical order. But if there where a way to read the images in alphabetical order , That will be good.

@AnasAlarja, Array.Sort(array_1)??? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-sort-an-array

@AnasAlarja I already gave you a link to what you want in an earlier comment. Please let us know if you need assistance using that.

What if the folder contains more than images?  Try this.
Private array_1() As String

Private Sub btn_Images_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Images.Click
    array_1 = Directory.GetFiles("D:\Downloads\new folder411")
    'select images
    array_1 = (From f In array_1
                  Let ext As String = IO.Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower
                  Where ext = ".jpg" OrElse
                    ext = ".png" OrElse
                    ext = ".bmp"
                  Select f).ToArray
End Sub

Private Sub btn_ChangeImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_ChangeImage.Click
    Static i As Integer = 0
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(array_1(i)) 'how do you know if the file is an image
    txt_Photo_URL.Text = array_1(i)
    i += 1
End Sub


Thank you for your answer. All the files in the folder were images. Please see my first comment in comments section of the question.
